# cannot access property of appended data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, append

I have a problem. This code worked when the html was static and not appended, but when append data it does not...

I have appended data from a JSON-document like so:

```
$('#articles').append('<article><time pubdate="pubdate">' + pubDate + '</time><h2><a href="#">' + headline + '</a></h2><p>' + bodyText + '</p></article>');
```

After this I create a variable containing the first article:

```
var currentElement = $("article:first");
```

Then I want to access currentElement.position():

```
console.log(currentElement.position());
```

But it comes back as undefined... It worked with unappended data? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Here is the entire code:

```
$(document).ready(onDocumentReady);     

    function onDocumentReady()
    {
        console.log('Document ready'); 

        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'data.json',
            dataType:'json',
            success: jsonParser
        });

        function jsonParser(json)
        {
            $.getJSON('data.json',runData)


            function runData(data)
            {   
                $.each(data.article, writeData)

                function writeData(keys,values)
                {


                    var pubDate = values.pubDate;
                    var headline = values.headline;
                    var bodyText = values.bodyText;

                    $('#articles').append('<article><time pubdate="pubdate">' + pubDate + '</time><h2><a href="#">' + headline + '</a></h2><p>' + bodyText + '</p></article>');
                }
            }

        }



        var currentElement = $("article:first");

        console.log(currentElement.position());
```

EDIT AGAIN:

When I

```
console.log(currentElement);
```

I get:

[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "article:first", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
context: document
length: 0
prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1]
selector: "article:first"
**proto**: Object[0]

Don't really understand that stuff, but thought it might help

**UPDATE:
If I do a setTimeOut like this, I am able to access the element:**

```
setTimeout(function()
        {
        var currentElement = $("article:first");
        console.log(currentElement);
        console.log(currentElement.position().left);
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: $("#articles:first") .. u miss the` #`

Comment: @Sarath no OP didn't miss any '#'

Comment: Your posted code should work, you are making something wrong elsewhere. Provide the context of where/how you are using this code

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/24nQn/1/)!!

Comment: Everything posted now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$("article:first-child")`

#### Edit

Never mind `:first` works in jQuery.

Comment: why it should be that?

Answer (score 0):

Please make your ajax is returning data and article elements are getting created .  If no elements are getting created  then it will return undefined.

Comment: The elements are getting created. I simply cannot access their positions

Answer (score 0):

Before the success function, try to add: `async: false` in your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'data.json',            
            dataType:'json',
            async:false,
            success: runData(data)
        });
        function runData(data){   
            $.each(data.article, writeData)
            function writeData(keys,values){
                var pubDate = values.pubDate;
                var headline = values.headline;
                var bodyText = values.bodyText;
                $('#articles').append('<article><time pubdate="pubdate">' + pubDate + '</time><h2><a href="#">' + headline + '</a></h2><p>' + bodyText + '</p></article>');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but makes no difference :(

Comment: Ok, it seems that $.getJSON() makes always an asynchronus call to fetch your data, but since you're using $ajax, i think you could pass 'data' to your function, without using $.getJSON